# Llamar java controller desde AngularJs

Tags: java, angularjs, mvc, controller

Qué  tal, mi situación es la siguiente.
Tengo el html en el cual mando llamar mi Angularjs sin embargo al llamar  el java Controller desde el factory con $http  me marca "not found" en el path del url, en el conttoller esta el @RequestMapping, pero no logro ejecutar el controlador.
Todo esto lo tengo en NetBeans 8.2 con spring mvc

-- Código html

```
  <div data-ng-app="myApp">
      <div data-ng-controller="MyController">
          <button data-ng-click="getDataFromServer()">
              Test Angularjs
          </button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

-- AngularJS

```
var app = angular
    .module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])    
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope, $service, $http, $resource) {          
            $scope.getDataFromServer = function () {                 
                $service.JS_STST_GetData();
            }
       }) // end controller
    .factory(
        '$service',
        function ($http) {
            return {
                JS_STST_GetData: function () {
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: '/TestMaping',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        }
                    }).then(_success, _error);
                },
```

-- Código Java Controller

```
@Controller
public class VerController {        
    @RequestMapping(value="/TestMaping", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String TEST(Model model){
        return "Test";
    }        
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String otroMetodo(Model model){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Por favor, para poder ayudarte tu pregunta tiene que cumplir con ciertas especificaciones: añade el código relacionado, tanto de javascript como de java, para que podamos entender el escenario

Comment: Has intentado acceder desde el navegador?

Comment: Si, he estado revisando un poco más, al parecer es la parte de la estructura de las carpetas, soy algo nuevo en java y no se donde va esa configuración, por eso el mapeo no detecta el llamado al controller de java

Comment: En este codigo: `public String TEST(Model model){
        return "Test";
    } ` que es "Test"?, una vista o simplemente un texto que intentas devolver?

Comment: Es una vista...